# android opengl es 2 not working on all devices

Tags: android, drawing, opengl-es-2.0

I'm having a little trouble with my app.. I developed my app using a samsung galaxy S3 to test it and everything turned out ok!
But here is the problem, after I finished the app I began to test in other devices. The app ran perfectly on other Galaxy S3 and a Galaxy S. But when I tried to run it on a Sony Xperia and a LG Optimus Net Dual, the screen simply turns out black!

The more interesting is that the app on these devices, the sound funcions OK, the ads appears and the app is respondig perfectly to touches, but only draw a black screen! It's really weird... It's like they dont support opengles 2 but they do and the android version are 4.0 ICS on Xperia and 2.2 on the LG!

Does Anyone know what this is? Or got simillar problems? If anyone wants code just say and post here! Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

my load texture:

```
    public static int loadTexture(final int ResourceId, final int min_filter, final int mag_filter) {
    for (int i=0;i<nTextures;i++) if (Textures[i*2]==ResourceId) return Textures[i*2+1];
    int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
     if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
        {
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(GLRenderer.mContext.getResources(), ResourceId, options);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, min_filter);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, mag_filter);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GLES20.GL_RGBA, bitmap, 0);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        if (textureHandle[0] == 0) throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
        Textures[nTextures*2]=ResourceId;
        Textures[nTextures*2+1]=textureHandle[0];
        nTextures++;
        return textureHandle[0];
}
```

EDIT 2:

my GLSurfaceView's create:

```
    GLActivityView(GLActivity context) {
        super(context);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
//      getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
//      setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8);
        renderer = new GLRenderer(context);
        setRenderer(renderer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps those phones do not support the NPOT feature. If NPOTs are not supported then you may want to make sure your textures dimensions are all powers of 2.

You can check like this

```
static public boolean isNPOTSupported(GL10 gl) {
    String extensions = gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);
    return extensions.indexOf("GL_OES_texture_npot") != -1;
}
```

Comment: by NPOT do you mean non power of 2? im a little noob... Yes, all the textures are indeed power of 2 but they are not square. Some are 512x256 for example.. the only pic npot is the icon that is 96x96 but i dont load it on the opengl..

Comment: Hmm then I don't know.. There must be something else specific to opengl 2 which is not supported somewhere.. Anyway does it run on the emulator? Emulator now supports opengl

Comment: well, i tried now but it return the "no configs match configspec" error that is the error when you dont heve support for opengles2 right? on the devices thats not what happens. The screen is simply black, it doesnt give errors...

Comment: i found something.. when I commented the setEGLContextClientVersion(2); I was able to reproduce the same state. The ads work, the music work but the screen were black! now is returning the error "called unimplemented method openGL ES API" on the logcat. How do I prevent this?

Comment: @rdnobrega hmmm yes it sounds like you've picked the incorrect GL config. However, you might also use unsupported texture compression that's why you get empty screen. Please review all supported configs here: http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro25&D=LG+P698&testgroup=egl
I've ran into situation similar to yours, please do you have config with needed colors and buffers depth available on these devices.

Comment: @keaukraine i'm not sure what are you saying.. can you explain more to me? my textures are all png 32 bit (8bit per channel) saved through photoshop.. my loadtexture method is above for you to see...

Comment: @keatkraie I can see that the LG P698 runs opengles 2. In that case, is that possible to resolve this issue with setEGLConfigChooser(5, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0);?